# Creating a set of inline divs which expand their width to fill their parent - but which also break to form a new line when their min-width is reached

Tags: html, css, flexbox

this is my first post here,

I enjoy a html challenge, but I have no idea for this issue, and I was hoping to get some help. Thank you in advance for any takers.

So I simply want to create a set of inline divs/buttons which expand their width to full their parent div. This is relatively easy, with the code below (which I found on stackoverflow):

```
<div class="btn-holder">
  <button type="button">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button">Button 3</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-holder">
  <button type="button">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button">Button 3</button>
  <button type="button">Button 4</button>
  <button type="button">Button 5</button>
  <button type="button">Button 6</button>
  <button type="button">Button 7</button>
  <button type="button">Button 8</button>
  <button type="button">Button 9</button>
  <button type="button">Button 10</button>
  <button type="button">Button 11</button>
  <button type="button">Button 12</button>
</div>

<style>
.btn-holder {
  display: flex;
}

.btn-holder button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: fit-content;
}
</style>
```

This code is basically fine for the first example of only three buttons. But when there are 12 buttons, they all cram or overflow the parent div as it only uses a single line.

My needs really require the buttons to have a min-width of 'fit-content', and the parent div should break into a second or third line, if that makes sense.

The closest I can come to this is actually to simply 'text-align: justify;' the buttons - but I cannot see how to 'flex-grow' the button.

```
<style>
.btn-holder {
  text-align: justify;
}

.btn-holder button {
  min-width: fit-content;
  width: maximize-to-fill-parent; /* Imaginary command */
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Any geniuses out there who can see a solution? Cheers if so!

Comment: try `flex-wrap: wrap` on `.btn-holder`.

Comment: oh boy, that was magically simple and easy! Thank you. This really demonstrates my lack of knowledge on display: flex;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying flex-wrap: wrap to the containing div solves the issue.

```css
.btn-holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.btn-holder button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-holder">
  <button type="button">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button">Button 3</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-holder">
  <button type="button">Button 1</button>
  <button type="button">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button">Button 3</button>
  <button type="button">Button 4</button>
  <button type="button">Button 5</button>
  <button type="button">Button 6</button>
  <button type="button">Button 7</button>
  <button type="button">Button 8</button>
  <button type="button">Button 9</button>
  <button type="button">Button 10</button>
  <button type="button">Button 11</button>
  <button type="button">Button 12</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid for the solution being so simple (and obviously showing I know nothing of display: flex;), but really happy about how easy it is. I've already implemented it on my website, and it looks great!